# Android: Open non-readable directories

Tags: android, file, shell, unix, root

Is there a good way to get informations of files, directories, links... inside a non-readable directory?

Currently I use Chainfire´s libsuperuser library which enables my app to run Shell commands like `ls -l` with root/superuser permission. So I´m able to list the content of directories like '/data/data'.

Example of / directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x root     root              1970-08-10 14:44 acct
drwxrwx--- system   cache             2014-08-06 18:03 cache
-rwxr-x--- root     root       272364 1970-01-01 01:00 charger
dr-x------ root     root              1970-08-10 14:44 config
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1970-08-10 14:44 d -> /sys/kernel/debug
drwxrwx--x system   system            2014-08-05 20:33 data
-rw-r--r-- root     root          286 1970-01-01 01:00 default.prop
drwxr-xr-x root     root              2014-08-05 20:36 dev
lrwxrwxrwx root     root              1970-08-10 14:44 etc -> /system/etc
and so on...
```

For my root file manager project I would like to wrap these information into Java objects. But the problem is that the output of 'ls -l' is quite difficult to parse (since user can use whitespace in filenames, maybe different 'ls' output on different android versions...). So even if I´m able to make a parser which is able to read 'ls -l' output it is probably very buggy and unreliable.

So now I´d like to ask whether there is a better solution to get file information (like unix-permission, owner, group...) in a non-readable directory?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The ls command has different options for different details, but ultimately you likely will need to parse the output.  Your title is a bit misleading though "root directory" normally means the root of the directory tree (ie, "/"), not one which you are running as the superuser in order to be able to access.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I changed the title. I could not find any option of 'ls' which makes it easier to parse the output. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a regular expression to extract the file name from each line:

```
\d{2}:\d{2}\s(.+)$
```

I'm assuming that the output of the `ls` command is always the same:

```
drwxrwx--- system   cache             2014-08-06 18:03 cache
```

where we have some file information, date, time and the file name. So, your code would be something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\s(.+)$");

for (String line : lsLines) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        String filename;
        String tempFilename = matcher.group(1);

        if (tempFilename.indexOf(" -> ") > -1) {
            filename = tempFilename.split(" -> ")[1];
        } else {
            filename = tempFilename;
        }

        // Do something with filename
    }
}
```